# Select Column Values from all the tables of database ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I am trying to fetch column value from all the tables of database where column value matches.

```
Table A
CAMPUS_ID
1

Table B
CAMPUS_ID
1
```

Expected Result

```
TABLE   VALUE
A       1 
TABLE   VALUE
B       1
```

Query

```
SELECT CAMPUS_ID FROM (SELECT A.TABLE_NAME FROM
user_tables A JOIN user_tab_columns C ON C.TABLE_NAME = 
A.TABLE_NAME WHERE C.COLUMN_NAME = 'CAMPUS_ID')
WHERE CAMPUS_ID = '1'
```

**Error Invalid Identifier**

Inner query return the correct tables.

Comment: You can't mix data and metadata. You'll need to use dynamic SQL, ie generate your SQL from the metadata, and then execute it.

Comment: What's the point in including the `value` column in the expected result? That will never be different to the one you want to put in the WHERE clause. What if there are multiple rows where `campus_id = 1` in those tables? What if there are no rows at all that match that condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select table_name, 
       extractvalue(
          xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||table_name||' where campus_id = 1')),
         '/ROWSET/ROW/C'
       ) as count
from user_tables ut
where exists (select *
              from user_tab_columns c 
              where c.table_name = ut.table_name
                and c.column_name = 'CAMPUS_ID');
```

`dbms_xmlgen.getxml` runs the passed SQL statement and returns the result as an XML value. `extracvalue()` is then used to extract the actual rowcount.

This will return the table name and the count of rows in that table where `campus_id = 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
select table_name from dba_tab_columns where column_name='THE_COLUMN_YOU_LOOK_FOR';
```

If you don't have DBA privileges, you can try this:

```
select table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name='THE_COLUMN_YOU_LOOK_FOR';
```